# Substituir string lida de um arquivo

Tags: php

Estou criando uma rotina usando o `Symfony console` para criar novos controllers a partir de um arquivo de template pre-existente, porém na hora de realizar a busca pelo `pattern` definido neste template, a class `SplFileObject` pula e as vezes ignora algumas linhas;

```
public function writeWithTemplate($template)
{
    try {
        $this->template = new \SplFileObject(__DIR__ . "/templates/{$template}", "r");

        $pattern = '@' . strtoupper($template) . '@';

        while (!$this->template->eof()) {
            $this->file->fwrite($this->template->fgets());
        }
        return true;
    } catch(\Exception $error) {

        return false;
    }
}
```

o `$this->file` também é um arquivo aberto usando o `SplFileObject`, desta maneira que esta a função a mesma funciona perfeitamente, porém se eu fizer algumas comparações dentro do `while`  o `write` não é aplicado corretamente.

o arquivo template é:

```
<?php

namespace App\Controller;

use App\Controller\Controller;
use Psr\Http\Message\ServerRequestInterface as Request;
use Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface as Response;

class @CONTROLLER@ extends Controller
{

    public function main(Request $request, Response $response)
    {

    }
}
```

Note que existe uma marcação `@CONTROLLER@` que é onde eu desejo fazer a substituição, se eu fizer uma verificação dentro do while;

```
...
while (!$this->template->eof()) {
    if (strpos($this->template->fgets(), $pattern) !== false) {
       $line = str_replace($pattern, $this->fileName, $this->template->fgets());
    }         
    $line = empty($line) ? $this->template->fgets() : $line;
    $this->file->fwrite($line); 
}
```

Algumas vezes o arquivo gerado sai apenas com `}` (1 ou mais) e diversas outras combinações sem sentido.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pode ter mais problemas no seu código, mas um evidente é esse:

Aqui você pegar uma linha e ve se o *pattern* está nessa linha:

```
if (strpos($this->template->fgets(), $pattern) !== false) {
//                          ^^^^^ leu uma linha
```

mas em seguida você **pega uma nova linha** e tenta trocar o pattern nessa nova:

```
   $line = str_replace($pattern, $this->fileName, $this->template->fgets());
   //                                                              ^^^^^ leu outra
```

Ou seja, você está descartando a maior parte das linhas com o *pattern*, e tentando trocar o pattern em alguma linha que não sabe se realmente precisa.

Mais sentido faria isso:

```
$line = $this->template->fgets();
if (strpos($line , $pattern) !== false) {
    $line = str_replace($pattern, $this->fileName, $line );
}
```

Na verdade, precisa ver se justifica ter o `if`. Supondo que não seja algo pra ser executado a todo instante, bastaria isso:

```
while (!$this->template->eof()) {
    $line = $this->template->fgets();
    if(!empty($line)) $this->file->fwrite(str_replace($pattern, $this->fileName, $line));
}
```

Queira quer não, o `strpos` tem algum custo. É um pouco menor do que o do `str_replace`, mas muito provavelmente o ganho não compensa nesse cenário (imagino que seu arquivo gerado seja o cache para uso normal, e você só consuma o template quando tem alguma mudança).

Comment: Entendi bem! obrigado!, a unica coisa que achei estranho é a questão do `fgets()`, se eu usar 3x `$this->template->fgets();` mesmo dentro do while eu vou pegar 3 linhas de uma só vez? eu achei que pegar a linha era condicional ao `eof()` e que seria ele que determinaria em qual linha o ponteiro estaria.

Comment: `eof` (**E**nd **O**f **F**ile) é usado no `while` pra saber se chegou no fim do arquivo. Quem pega a linha é o `fgets`. Tá certo que o pessoal vai liberar o saque do "fgets" em fevereiro, mas não é bom abusar no código :P

Comment: http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/splfileobject.fgets.php

Comment: Sim bacco, eu sei o que é eof, o que eu tinha em mente é que o eof trabalharia junto ao fgets para saber em qual linha colocar o ponteiro.